# Constructing 3-step sql query

Tags: syntax, rails

I have:

- a table of `Characters` with a `character_id` column;
- a join table of `Chats` with `character_id` and `conversation_id` columns;
- and a table of `Conversations` with a `conversation_id` column.

I am trying to construct a query that finds the Conversation between two characters (`sender` and `recipient`) and ONLY those two characters (other conversations may exist with sender, recipient, and other characters involved - group conversations).

I'm using **Ruby on Rails**.

The query involves three steps:

1. Find all Conversations belonging to sender.
2. Select from these the ones that also belong to recipient.
3. Select from these the one that belongs only to sender and recipient.

I can't get the query quite right. The best I've managed is below.

Where am I going wrong?

The query below gives this error: `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP"`

```
SELECT Conversations.id FROM
(
    (
        (
            Conversations INNER JOIN ( SELECT conversation_id FROM Chats WHERE Chats.character_id=#{sender_id} ) AS sterling
                          ON Chats.conversation_id=Conversations.id
        )
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT conversation_id FROM Chats WHERE Chats.character_id=#{recipient_id} ) AS archer
        ON Chats.conversation_id=Conversations.id
    )
    GROUP BY conversation_id
    HAVING COUNT(Chats.conversation_id)=2
);
```

Comment: I want to use archer in the count. I only added `AS sterling` and `AS archer` because I originally wrote the query without them, and I got the error `subquery in FROM must have an alias`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
SELECT id FROM Conversations
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT conversation_id FROM Chats  WHERE Chats.character_id= '#{sender_id}' 
) AS sterling
    ON sterling.conversation_id = Conversations.id
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT conversation_id FROM Chats WHERE Chats.character_id = '#{recipient_id}' 
) AS archer
    ON archer.conversation_id = Conversations.id;
```

Since those are inner join, it has to be in both sender and recipient. It will only return conversation which are in both 3 tables.

The count does not seem useful here unless you are trying to get something like people with more than 1 conversation together.

It should also work with this simpler version although it does not check for the existence of `conversation_id` in `Conversations`:

```
SELECT conversation_id 
FROM Chats AS sterling
INNER JOIN  Chats AS archer
    ON sterling.conversation_id = archer.conversation_id
WHERE sterling.character_id = '#{recipient_id}' 
    AND archer.character_id = '#{sender_id}';
```

Exit with count:

```
SELECT cv.conversation_id
FROM (
    SELECT conversation_id 
    FROM Chats AS sterling
    INNER JOIN  Chats AS archer
        ON sterling.conversation_id = archer.conversation_id
    WHERE sterling.character_id = '#{recipient_id}' 
    GROUP BY conversation_id 
    HAVING count(distinct character_id) = 2
) ce
INNER JOIN  Chats AS ch
        ON ce.conversation_id = ch.conversation_id
    WHERE ch.character_id = '#{sender_id}';
```

Comment: I was getting the complaint `ERROR: column reference "conversation_id" is ambiguous`, so after much trial and error I got the code below, which doesn't have any errors. I think it works as desired, but would not be surprised if someone corrects it!

Comment: 'having' is always sub-optimal, because it happens after the query results are compiled.

Answer (score 1):

• *Select Conversations that have two parties (as a subquery)*

```
(SELECT g.conversation_id 
 FROM (
  SELECT conversation_id,count(recipient_id) as members 
  FROM Chats group by conversation_id) g,(*above*) rc 
  WHERE g.members=2
 ) co;
```

• *Find all Conversations belonging to sender. (as a subquery)*

```
(SELECT co.conversation_id 
 FROM Chats ch, (*above*) co 
 WHERE ch.character_id=#{sender_id} 
 AND co.conversation_id=ch.conversation_id
) sc
```

• *Select from these the ones that also belong to recipient*

```
SELECT sc.conversation_id 
FROM Chats ch,(*above*) sc 
WHERE ch.character_id=#{recipient_id} 
AND sc.conversation_id=ch.conversation_id
```

Putting this together...

```
SELECT sc.conversation_id 
FROM Chats ch,
 (SELECT co.conversation_id 
  FROM Chats ch,
   (SELECT g.conversation_id 
    FROM (
    SELECT conversation_id,count(recipient_id) as members 
    FROM Chats group by conversation_id) g,(*above*) rc 
    WHERE g.members=2
   ) co   
  WHERE ch.character_id=#{sender_id} 
  AND co.conversation_id=ch.conversation_id
 ) sc 
WHERE ch.character_id=#{recipient_id} 
AND sc.conversation_id=ch.conversation_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT senderConversations.conversation_id FROM Chats AS senderConversations
INNER JOIN Chats AS recipientConversations
    ON senderConversations.conversation_id=recipientConversations.conversation_id
WHERE senderConversations.character_id='#{sender_id}'
    AND recipientConversations.character_id='#{recipient_id}'
GROUP BY senderConversations.conversation_id
HAVING count(distinct senderConversations.character_id) = 2
```

Comment: 'having' is always sub-optimal, because it happens after the query results are compiled.